# Do restaurants have ugly sections?

Tags: economics

Disclaimer: asked on Travel SE https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154682/13746 but was closed.

---

There's a theory that restaurants have a section for good looking people and a section for ugly people.

Fox News has an article: [Restaurants hide ugly patrons in the back, social experiment finds](https://www.foxnews.com/food-drink/restaurants-hide-ugly-patrons-in-the-back-social-experiment-finds).

The Straight Dope has a forum post: [Do restaurants try to "hide" ugly or unattractive customers?](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=753786)

I wouldn't really hold my breath over what Fox News and a random forum online has to say, though. Is there any merit to these claims of ugly sections in restaurants?

Comment: Hm.... do you expect "hard data" on this? Like, a scan of a memo to one restaurant's waiters to place less attractive people in the back? Or would it have to be multiple restaurants? How many? From how many different countries? And how would you define "ugly"? That could range from "less attractive" all the way to spoil-your-appetite disfigurement or skin conditions. If waiters place someone from the latter category somewhat out-of-sight of the other customers if such a customer should enter their venue, is that "having a section for ugly people" or just common sense?